# Checking if a directory exists on another server in ksh

Tags: networking, directory, ksh

I am trying to verify if a directory exists prior to moving a file in Korn, using the classic:

```
    if [[ -d ${dir} ]]; then
        scp file
    else
        exit 12
    fi
```

**My Problem:** 
 That the directory is on another server, so whenever I check, the script can't find it and therefore fails and exits every time. 
**My Question:** 
 Is there a way to do a "-d" across the network, perhaps using sftp/scp-like functionality? The user currently does not have to enter a password and can scp fine, so that is one less issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
ssh user@host test -d ${dir}
```

Comment: Thanks much...worked out perfectly, just did:
ssh user@host test -d ${dir}
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
             etc...

Comment: `if ssh ...; then `  should work as well .. if you prefer one-liners.